# Как переключать слайды в owl-carousel стрелками клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

В документации к библиотеке не нашел реализации прокрутки слайдов стрелками клавиатуры. Как это можно реализовать?

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на стрелку вверх и стрелку вправо переключалось на следующий по очереди слайд, при нажатии на стрелку вниз и влево - соответственно на предыдущий.
Плюс, при скроллинге вниз и вверх на мобильных и планшетах слайды тоже должны свайпиться, пока-что удалось только реализовать эффект анимации скролла вниз-вверх(`animateOut: "slideOutUp",animateIn: "slideInUp"`)
 Слайдер:

```
<article class="owl-carousel main-carousel hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <section class="portfolio-slide">
        <div class="col-xs-12 portfolio-slide-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-img-block">
                <img src="img/beekeper_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
                <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
                <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text ">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
                    <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
                    <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolio-slide">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-slide-content">
            <div class="col-xs-8 work-img-block">
                <img src="img/beekeper_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 work-info">
                <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
                <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text ">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
                    <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
                    <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-slide-content">
            <div class="col-xs-8 work-img-block">
                <img src="img/studnet_support_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 work-info">
                <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">Studnet</h1>
                <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
                    <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
                    <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolio-slide">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-slide-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-img-block">
                <img src="img/beekeper_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
                <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
                <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text ">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
                    <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
                    <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-slide-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12  work-img-block">
                <img src="img/studnet_support_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
                <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">Studnet</h1>
                <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
                    <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
                    <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-slide-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-img-block">
                <img src="img/gulfstream_app_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
                <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
                <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
                <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
                    <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
                    <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</article>
```

Инициализация и настройка через owl-carousel:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var owl = $(".main-carousel");
        owl.owlCarousel({
            items:1,
            loop:true,
            nav: true,
            dots: true,
            autoplay:false,
            autoplayTimeout:5000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true
        });
        owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
            if (e.deltaY>0) {
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var owl = $(".mobile-carousel");
        owl.owlCarousel({
            items:1,
            loop:true,
            nav: true,
            dots: true,
            animateOut: "slideOutUp",
            animateIn: "slideInUp",
            autoplay:false,
            autoplayTimeout:5000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true
        });
        owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
            if (e.deltaY>0) {
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Покажите код того, что уже у вас есть

Comment: @Cheg Добавил верстку слайдера и его инициализацию. Если нужно добавить и мобильный слайдер(там в article вместо класса main-carousel используется класс mobile-carousel) - напишите, добавлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример прокрутки по нажатию стрелок влево/вправо:

```js
var owl = $(".main-carousel");
owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplayTimeout: 5000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true
});
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl');
  } else {
    owl.trigger('next.owl');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
owl.on('mouseover mouseout', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('keydown');
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (owl.hasClass('keydown')) {
    if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<article class="owl-carousel main-carousel hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <section class="portfolio-slide">
    <div class="col-xs-12 portfolio-slide-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-img-block">
        <img src="img/beekeper_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
        <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
        <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text ">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
          <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
          <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="portfolio-slide">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-slide-content">
      <div class="col-xs-8 work-img-block">
        <img src="img/beekeper_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 work-info">
        <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
        <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text ">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
          <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
          <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-slide-content">
      <div class="col-xs-8 work-img-block">
        <img src="img/studnet_support_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 work-info">
        <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">Studnet</h1>
        <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
          <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
          <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="portfolio-slide">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-slide-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-img-block">
        <img src="img/beekeper_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
        <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
        <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text ">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
          <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
          <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-slide-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12  work-img-block">
        <img src="img/studnet_support_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
        <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">Studnet</h1>
        <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
          <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
          <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-slide-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-img-block">
        <img src="img/gulfstream_app_thumb.png" class="img-responsive work-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 work-info">
        <h1 class="text-center col-xs-12 work-info-header">BeeKeeper</h1>
        <p class="work-info-text">The beekeeper's handbook with online-store. Developed by a private order. </p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">To upgrade and update the data you only need to connect to the network.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">It contains the necessary knowledge base of skilled beekeepers.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text">The application works with no access to the Internet.</p>
        <p class="work-info-text hidden-xs">So it is very comfortable to be used in the "field" conditions.</p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 apps-button">
          <a href="#" class="playmarket-button">Link to Google Play</a>
          <a href="#" class="appstore-button">Link to AppStore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Для прокрутки по свайпу предлагаю использовать [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin).

К сожалению, в сниппете не получается, воспроизвести данный пример:

```
var owl = $(".mobile-carousel");
owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: true,
  mouseDrag:false,
  pullDrag:false,
  touchDrag:false,
  freeDrag:false
});
owl.swipe({
  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
     owl.trigger('owl.next');
    }
    if (direction == 'up') {
     owl.trigger('owl.prev');
    }
  },
  threshold: 60,
  allowPageScroll: 'vertical'
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже нашел ответ на вопрос прокрутки стрелками(и даже стрелками вверх/вниз), осталось узнать как сделать свайп вверх/вниз на мобильных экранах

Answer (score 1):

Разобравшись, узнал как можно сделать прокрутку стрелками клавиатуры, если вдруг кому интересно - оставлю тут.
Итак, в моем случае в место инициализации функции надо добавить что-то вроде:

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                //влево
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                //вверх
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                //вправо
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                //вправо
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            }
        });
```

А полный код инициализацации, в моем случае, выглядит примерно так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var owl = $(".main-carousel");
        owl.owlCarousel({
            items:1,
            loop:true,
            nav: true,
            dots: true,
            autoplay:false,
            autoplayTimeout:5000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true
        });
        owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
            if (e.deltaY>0) {
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
        });
        $('body').keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                //влево
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                //вверх
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                //вправо
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                //вправо
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            }
        });
    });
```

Остается актуальным вопросом: как сделать прокрутку при свайпе вниз/вверх в мобильной версии? Если найду решение - кину сюда.

Comment: если нужен свайп, то лучше сразу slick использовать, там он хороший

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Посмотрел на него, но не вижу никаких опций для свайпа вверх/вниз, в owl-carousel в коробке есть анимация такой вещи, но в любом слайдере есть overflow: hidden, что мешает свайпать вверх/вниз, т.к. банально скроллинг вниз отключен.